# C# get all children of XElement regardless of their value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML structure:

```
<init_deinit>
    <step name="init">
        <call>...</call>
        <check>...</check>
        <call>...</call>
        <wait>...</wait>
        ....
    </step>
    <step name="deinit">
        ....
    </step>
</init_deinit>
```

There is a lot of examples of how to retrieve all descendants of a single type. I.E.:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml")
var all_call_tags = xdoc.Descendants("init_deinit").Elements("step").ElementAt(0).Elements("call");
```

But I need to retrieve ALL the children of the 'step' element and I need to retrieve them in the exact order thay are written in the XML. So what I need is something like IEnumerable iterator that contains XElements call, check, call and wait in this order. I tried but failed so far :)

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you all `Descendants` of `step` elements:

```
xdoc.Descendants("step").SelectMany(x => x.Descendants());
```

If you want `Descendants` of first `step` element use

```
xdoc.Descendants("step").First().Descendants();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

//Here you will get all the descendants of the first step 
xdoc.Descendants("step").First().Descendants();

//To get all Descendants of step elements:
var x = xdoc.Descendants("step").Descendants();
```